# Can't pull input-field value located beyond form tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

### Problem

I use popup calendar, which is launched via href. I need to pass 'document.tstest.timestamp' (date input field) parameter into javascript function. And all worked well, **BUT**:
I want to include this tag-file into another form, so I can't use form

```
<form name="tstest">
```

in my tag file. As a result, **without form** I **can't find document.timestamp** input-field (as I understand due window.object hierarchy)

My tag file:

```
<form name="tstest">
        <input type="Text" id="time_stamp" name="timestamp">
        <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp',
                 document.tstest.timestamp.value);"> showCalendar</a>
</form>

<script>
    function show_calendar(target, value) {
        ............
    }
</script>
```

Help me, please, to find out solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your element has an `id` attribute on it so you can just use `document.getElementById()` to get a reference to it. I'd suggest modifying your `show_calendar` function to either take the `id` or a reference to the element directly, though, since you'll likely need to reference it again inside of that function.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I would like to pull it by id from show_calendar function

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following anywhere on the page and get the element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("time_stamp");
var myVal = elem.value;
```

This would work too

```
<a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp',
             document.getElementById('time_stamp').value);"> showCalendar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.tstest as syntax instead use document.getElementById("time_stamp")

Also remember an id is unique so don't put 2 elements with a same I'd on a same page